# Autofac Cannot resolve parameter serviceScopeFactory of constructor 'Void

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac, .net-4.5

I get the following error when I try to inject IServiceScopeFactory in a class in my business layer: "Cannot resolve parameter 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory' of constructor 'Void"

I havent worked with AutoFac before so I am wondering what I am missing:

This is my code:

```
private static void ConfigureAutoFacIoC(ContainerBuilder builder, HttpConfiguration config, IAppBuilder app)
    {
        AutoFacRegister.RegisterDependency(builder, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        RegisterWebApiDependency(builder);

        builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(config);
        var container = builder.Build();
        // Set the dependency resolver to be Autofac.
        config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
        app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
        app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);
    }

public static class AutoFacRegister
{
    public static void RegisterDependency(ContainerBuilder builder, Assembly webApiAssembly)
    {
        RegisterDataLayer(builder);
        RegisterBusinessLayer(builder);
        RegisterShared(builder);
        RegisterPresentationLayer(builder, webApiAssembly);
    }

    private static void RegisterDataLayer(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<SBSContext>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterType<AgdaContext>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterType<MailingRepository>().As<IMailingRepository>();
        builder.RegisterType<MembershipRepository>().As<IMembershipRepository>();
        builder.RegisterType<CourseMomentRepository>().As<ICourseMomentRepository>();
        builder.RegisterType<MedalRepository>().As<IMedalRepository>();
        builder.RegisterType<PersonRepository>().As<IPersonRepository>();
        builder.RegisterType<CourseRepository>().As<ICourseRepository>();
        builder.RegisterType<OrganisationRepository>().As<IOrganisationRepository>();
        builder.RegisterType<FunctionRepository>().As<IFunctionRepository>();
        builder.RegisterType<PaymentRepository>().As<IPaymentRepository>();
        builder.RegisterType<ChargeCategoryRepository>().As<IChargeCategoryRepository>();
        builder.RegisterType<OutcodeRepository>().As<IOutcodeRepository>();
        builder.RegisterType<UserRepository>().As<IUserRepository>();
        builder.RegisterType<ViewPersonRepository>().As<IViewPersonRepository>();
        builder.RegisterType<AgdaRepository>().As<IAgdaRepository>();
        builder.RegisterType<ReportRepository>().As<IReportRepository>();
        builder.RegisterType<ReportManager>().As<IReportManager>();
        builder.RegisterType<CourseApplicationRepository>().As<ICourseApplicationRepository>();
        builder.RegisterType<RepdayRepository>().As<IRepdayRepository>();
        builder.RegisterType<ChargeCategoryRepository>().As<IChargeCategoryRepository>();
        builder.RegisterType<CommuneRepository>().As<ICommuneRepository>();
        builder.RegisterType<PapApiAmbassador>().As<IPapApiAmbassador>();
        builder.RegisterType<VolenteerRepository>().As<IVolenteerRepository>();
        builder.RegisterType<AgreementTypeRepository>().As<IAgreementTypeRepository>();
        builder.RegisterType<CourseMomentStatusRepository>().As<ICourseMomentStatusRepository>();
        builder.RegisterType<CourseTypeRepository>().As<ICourseTypeRepository>();
        builder.RegisterType<AttestationRepository>().As<IAttestationRepository>();

        builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(GenericRepository<,>)).As(typeof(IGenericRepository<,>));

    }

    private static void RegisterBusinessLayer(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        var bllAssembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().
            SingleOrDefault(assembly => assembly.GetName().Name == "SBS.Ferdinand.BusinessLayer");

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(IServiceScopeFactory).Assembly).As<IServiceScopeFactory>();

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(bllAssembly)
            .Where(x => x.Name.EndsWith("Handler"))
            .AsImplementedInterfaces();

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(bllAssembly)
            .Where(x => x.Name.EndsWith("Helper"))
            .AsImplementedInterfaces()
            .SingleInstance();

        builder.RegisterType<OrganisationMigrator>().As<IOrganisationMigrator>();
    }
    private static void RegisterShared(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<BaseRequestModel>().AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterType<ImpersonateUser>().As<IImpersonateUser>();
        builder.RegisterModule<NLogModule>();
        builder.RegisterType<ApiApplicationSettings>().As<IApiApplicationSettings>().SingleInstance();
    }

    private static void RegisterPresentationLayer(ContainerBuilder builder, Assembly webApiAssembly)
    {
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(webApiAssembly);
    }

    public static void RegisterHangfireDependency(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        RegisterDataLayer(builder);
        RegisterBusinessLayer(builder);
        RegisterShared(builder);
        builder.RegisterType<CronJobManager>().As<ICronJobManager>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    }
}
public class NLogModule : Autofac.Module
{
    private static void OnComponentPreparing(object sender, PreparingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Parameters = e.Parameters.Union(
            new[]
            {
                new ResolvedParameter(
                    (p, i) => p.ParameterType == typeof (ILogger),
                    (p, i) => LogManager.GetLogger(p.Member.DeclaringType.FullName))
            });
    }

    protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(IComponentRegistry componentRegistry, IComponentRegistration registration)
    {
        // Handle constructor parameters.
        registration.Preparing += OnComponentPreparing;
    }
}
```

where I try to inject the IServiceScopeFactory

```
public class PaymentHandler : IPaymentHandler
         {
            private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;

            public PaymentHandler(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
            {
        
               _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;

            }
         }
```

Comment: The tag description for `[.net-framework-version]` is _"For questions specifically on how to deal with .Net versions. For other questions on .Net, please use a .net + version tag."_ - is this what your question is about?

Comment: There was no tag for .net-framework 4.5 and I didnt have enough points to create a new tag. But I removed the incorrect one @DiplomacyNotWar

Comment: I added the .net-4-5 tag for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you're trying to kind of mix-and-match .NET 4.5 dependency injection (e.g., with the `DependencyResolver` mechanism in Web API) and new .NET Core dependency injection (e.g., `IServiceProvider`). The really short answer here is... you can't do that.

If you read the exception it tells you exactly what's missing:

`Cannot resolve parameter 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceScopeFactory'`

You have a constructor that takes an `IServiceScopeFactory`. You want Autofac to inject it. You didn't tell Autofac *where to get it*. No magic here: if you didn't register it with Autofac, Autofac's not going to be able to figure it out.

I'd guess what you want is the ability to create lifetime scopes inside that `PaymentHandler`. Since that's not really a thing in Web API with `DependencyResolver`, instead of trying to mix-and-match, you have to use Autofac directly.

Inject the `ILifetimeScope` instead.

```cs
public class PaymentHandler : IPaymentHandler
{
  private readonly ILifetimeScope _scope;

  public PaymentHandler(ILifetimeScope scope)
  {
    _scope = scope;
    // now you can do
    // using(var childScope = _scope.BeginLifetimeScope){ }
  }
}
```

At this point, [it'd be good to head over to the Autofac docs](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/index.html) to learn more about lifetime scopes and how to work with them. But this should get you unblocked.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked :) Another question, I implemented this with the idea that it would solve the errormessage "The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed" - I create a background thread that is trying to save to the database. But it didnt solve it, but it should work right?

Comment: Nope. Background thread will likely complete AFTER the request has completed, but once the request has completed the request lifetime scope gets disposed. You should Google for strategies on doing background work in ASP.NET, it's not "fall-down easy" especially when you get DI involved. Note there's been a lot of improvement in this area in .NET Core so if you have the opportunity to upgrade and get out of classic Web API, I'd do it.